# Watson Personality Insights Service for Android Application Sample

Tags: java, android, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, personality-insights

I want to use **Personality Insights Service** of IBM. I have downloaded **Hello Wold** sample code and trying to integrate **Personality Insights Service** in it.

My code is like below.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.ibm.bms.samples.android.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.core.api.BMSClient;
import com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.core.api.Request;
import com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.core.api.Response;
import com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.core.api.ResponseListener;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.personality_insights.v2.PersonalityInsights;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.personality_insights.v2.model.Profile;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ResponseListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView buttonText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_text);

        try {
            //initialize SDK with IBM Bluemix application ID and route
            //TODO: Please replace <APPLICATION_ROUTE> with a valid ApplicationRoute and <APPLICATION_ID> with a valid ApplicationId
            BMSClient.getInstance().initialize(this, "http://bluemixpersonality.mybluemix.net", "b8c06c80-83fa-4448-b770-3ff5b3f1fb84");
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            this.setStatus("Unable to parse Application Route URL\n Please verify you have entered your Application Route and Id correctly and rebuild the app", false);
            buttonText.setClickable(false);
        }
    }

    public void pingBluemix(View view) {

        TextView buttonText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_text);
        buttonText.setClickable(false);

        TextView errorText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error_text);
        errorText.setText("Pinging Bluemix");

        Log.i(TAG, "Pinging Bluemix");

        // Testing the connection to Bluemix by sending a Get request to the Node.js application, using this Activity to handle the response.
        // This Node.js code was provided in the MobileFirst Services Starter boilerplate.
        // The below request uses the IBM Mobile First Core sdk to send the request using the applicationRoute that was provided when initializing the BMSClient earlier.
        new Request(BMSClient.getInstance().getBluemixAppRoute(), Request.GET).send(this.getApplicationContext(), this);
    }

    private void setStatus(final String messageText, boolean wasSuccessful) {
        final TextView errorText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error_text);
        final TextView topText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top_text);
        final TextView bottomText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_text);
        final TextView buttonText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_text);
        final String topStatus = wasSuccessful ? "Yay!" : "Bummer";
        final String bottomStatus = wasSuccessful ? "You Are Connected" : "Something Went Wrong";

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                buttonText.setClickable(true);
                errorText.setText(messageText);
                topText.setText(topStatus);
                bottomText.setText(bottomStatus);
            }
        });
    }

    // Implemented for the response listener to handle the success response when Bluemix is pinged
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Response response) {

        Log.e("Response: ", response.getResponseText());

        String myProfile = "Call me Ishmael. Some years ago-never mind how long precisely-having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. It is a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation. Whenever I find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, drizzly November in my soul; whenever I find myself involuntarily pausing before coffin warehouses, and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet; and especially whenever my hypos get such an upper hand of me, that it requires a strong moral principle to prevent me from deliberately stepping into the street, and methodically knocking people's hats off-then, I account it high time to get to sea as soon as I can.";

        PersonalityInsights service = new PersonalityInsights();
        service.setUsernameAndPassword("{username}","{password}");

        Profile personalityProfile = service.getProfile(myProfile);
        Log.e("hahah: ", "" + personalityProfile);

        setStatus("", true);
        Log.i(TAG, "Successfully pinged Bluemix!");
    }

    // Implemented for the response listener to handle failure response when Bluemix is pinged
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Response response, Throwable throwable, JSONObject jsonObject) {
        // Blah Blah Code on Failing to connect to IBM.
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ibm.bms.samples.android.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android',
            name: 'core',
            version: '1.+',
            ext: 'aar',
            transitive: true
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-wrapper:1.0.3'
}
```

I have referred below link.

[How to call Watson Insights Service using java](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/personality-insights/api/v2/?java#profile)

I am getting bellow error.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATUZ9.png)

**Note: I have set CORRECT username & password for Personality Insights Service.**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit question and reduce your code to an MCVE. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Th exception says you have not provided the correct credentials!

Comment: But I have put correct credentials. It is the credential for Personality Insights Service, isn't it?@user2642282

Comment: I am assuming you set the creds on this line service.setUsernameAndPassword("{username}","{password}");
with your username and password
you can obtain those from VCAP_SERVICES under envioroment variables in your bluemix application

Comment: Actually I was following this [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_m3mBadUrQ] to get the service credentials. At that time I was getting INVALID CREDENTIAL error. Then I have made new App in BlueMix and follow above YOUTUBE link and got this [http://i.imgur.com/L0iyGkc.png] error. I have changed service credentials as suggested by you. But I am getting same (ABOVE) error.@Dudi

Comment: you might need to login to your bluemix account, go to the app and restart it. In addition, have you bounded your app with the service instance?

Comment: I have stop that App in bluemix account. But It is not getting started and YES I have uploaded started app code via Command Prompt@Dudi

Comment: check logs to see why its not starting... I suggest you also update the question so others can help you with your current situation

Comment: I think you did not get my point. The application which is not starting is in BlueMix, not in Android Studio. So, How can I check log there? And Thanks for your suggestion I will update my question soon. Do you know any **LINKS** that give some IDEA to get started with BlueMix with Android Application?@Dudi

Comment: fyi, there are logs, next to enviroment variables on the Bluemix console and there is also in cmd cf logs <app_name> --recent

Comment: Yes. I have seen now. Thanks for information. But log says `[39mRetrieve the security context from the cache.`. What does it mean?@Dudi

Comment: I have searched on Google and found that you have to pass parameters like content type, Header etc. The link is [https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/personality-insights/output.shtml]. But they do not provide information that How to add these parameters. Do you have any idea about it?@Dudi, @German Attanasio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you are using the `java-wrapper:1.0.3`. That's pretty old, and we fixed and improved the library a lot since that release.
The 401 means that you didn't provide the right credentials or the service URL is not correct. You can set the service URL by calling `service.setEndPoint()`

See the example below:

Update the dependency in gradle to be:

```
'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:5.3.0'
```

Then use this code:

```
PersonalityInsights service = new PersonalityInsights();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>");
service.setEndPoint("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api")

String text = "your text goes here...."
ProfileOptions options = new ProfileOptions.Builder()
  .text(text)
  .build();

Profile profile = service.profile(options).execute();
System.out.println(profile);
```

Make sure you have credentials for the **Personality Insights** service(`tiered` plan). If you need help take a look at this [guide](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk#getting-the-service-credentials).
Finally your service credentials **are not** your Bluemix credentials.

Comment: pls read through the comments, the guy passed the credentials error. The question was not updated to reflect it

Comment: In any case he needs to update the library. I wrote the library and I know he will get issues when using the Profile class.

Comment: I have newly created app and service in Bluemix. But not uploaded it via command prompt. Yes as @GermanAttanasio told, I have updated LIBRARY and got INVALID CREDENTIAL error. Than I used credentials which are placed in **VCAP_SERVICES** tab under **ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE** in my Bluemix application as told by Dudi earlier. I got the **RESPONSE**. I got [http://i.imgur.com/mR29kU2.png] this response which is not identical to [http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/personality-insights/api/v2/?java#profile] thread under **Example response** heading. Is it CORRECT res?

Comment: Thanks. But I am not getting `word_count` and `word_count_message` in that response.@GermanAttanasio

Comment: did you check if they are not at the end of the printed json

Comment: I have printed it in Log and I have checked very well. There is no word count in that JSON. Instead the whole JSON is also not getting printed unlike [http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/personality-insights/api/v2/?java#profile] here under Example Response heading.@GermanAttanasio

Comment: I think the problem was the sdk version you were using Maulik. I just checked and I'm getting word count in the json response